# How to get the 1st of September from the previous September?

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2014

If I want to select a date relative to today's date I can do something like:

```
DateAdd(month, -2, N'1-Jan-2019')
```

This will give me the 1st of November 2018.

How would I get the Date of the 1st of September, from the previous year?

E.G

Say it's July 2019,
I want the 1st of September 2018, NOT 2019.

However,

Say it's November 2019,
I want the 1st of September 2019, NOT 2018.

How is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you always want September, or is there other math happening that I'm not catching here?

Comment: I only care about September 1st from whichever September was most recently in the past

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by subtracting 8 months from your `date` value and then using the resulting `year` to build up your September date:

```
declare @d table(d date);
insert into @d values ('20170101'),('20180101'),('20181101'),('20190101'),('20191001'),('20190901'),('20190921'),('20190808');

select d
      ,datefromparts(year(dateadd(month,-8,d)),9,1) as PrevSeptDate
      ,datetimefromparts(year(dateadd(month,-8,d)),9,1,0,0,0,0) as PrevSeptDateTime
from @d
order by d;
```

## Output

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+
|     d      | PrevSeptDate |    PrevSeptDateTime     |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+
| 2017-01-01 | 2016-09-01   | 2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2018-01-01 | 2017-09-01   | 2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2018-11-01 | 2018-09-01   | 2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-01 | 2018-09-01   | 2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2019-08-08 | 2018-09-01   | 2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2019-09-01 | 2019-09-01   | 2019-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2019-09-21 | 2019-09-01   | 2019-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2019-10-01 | 2019-09-01   | 2019-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Why would you use `datetimefromparts()` instead of `datefromparts()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Habit 